# How to remove shell from docker image with healthcheck?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have an [NGINX docker image](https://github.com/ammnt/nginx/blob/http3/Dockerfile) where I use healthcheck, like this:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=3s --timeout=1s \
CMD nc -vz -w1 127.0.0.1 8080 || exit 1
```

For security reasons, I also want to remove the shell, but healthcheck stops working after that. I tried to completely delete the busybox (alpine-basilayout), separately only remove symbolyc link for /bin/sh, replace shell with tiny etc.

How to do this correctly so as not to disrupt the application in the container and save healthcheck?

Comment: Please always include relevant code and configuration *in your question*; don't rely on links to external sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CMD` directive has two forms. When you write this:

```
CMD nc -vz -w1 127.0.0.1 8080 || exit 1
```

That gets translated to `sh -c 'nc -vz -w1 127.0.0.1 8080 || exit 1`. You can avoid that shell execution by using the "exec" form the `CMD` directive, like this:

```
CMD ["nc", "-vz", "-w1", "127.0.0.1", "8080"]
```

That will execute `nc` directly, without involving the shell. Note that your existing healthcheck is *explicitly* using shell syntax (the `|| exit 1`) part; that won't work if you're not using the shell.

---

For example, a container built with this Dockerfile will never be healthy:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add darkhttpd curl
RUN rm -f /bin/sh

ENTRYPOINT ["darkhttpd"]
CMD ["/var/www/localhost/htdocs", "--port", "8080"]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=3s --timeout=1s \
CMD nc -vz -w1 127.0.0.1 8080
```

But this one works as desired:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add darkhttpd curl
RUN rm -f /bin/sh

ENTRYPOINT ["darkhttpd"]
CMD ["/var/www/localhost/htdocs", "--port", "8080"]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=3s --timeout=1s \
CMD ["nc", "-vz", "-w1", "127.0.0.1", "8080"]
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. But I already tried it before with /usr/bin/nc instead just nc. I can try it again... Can I remove /bin/sh after that?

Comment: That is what I am suggesting with this answer, yes.